# Eclipse Juno Update causes it to crash

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I ran Eclipse Juno's update just now and when it restarted it crashed leaving an error log file shown below.

```
!SESSION 2013-11-21 18:11:02.663 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_17
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2013-11-21 18:11:03.716
!MESSAGE [SCR] Exception while activating instance org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@1c200d0 of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 15 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2013-11-21 18:11:03.719
!MESSAGE [SCR] Exception while activating instance org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@1c200d0 of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 15 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-11-21 18:11:04.975
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (245).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 42 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 42 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui_2.3.0.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui_5.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_5.1.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui_7.2.0.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui_[5.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui_2.3.1.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb_4.1.1.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui_2.1.0.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.core_7.2.0.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.core 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui_7.2.0.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui_[5.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.launch_7.1.0.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.launch 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_[5.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.launch 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui_[5.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf_2.3.0.201302132326.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.dsf 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-21 18:11:05.012
!MESSAGE Bundle .... more
```

What might have gone wrong?

Comment: Are your OS, your java-version and your eclipse version all 32 bits?

Comment: Yes. They are all 32-bit. Sorry for the delay. We went out for a coffee.